# Compute integral: $\int _1^8\left(\sqrt[3]{r}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{r}}\right)\:dr$

Tags: calculus

Compute this integral: $$\int _1^8\left(\sqrt[3]{r}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{r}}\right)\:dr$$

My attempt:

$$\int \sqrt[3]{r}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{r}}dr$$

$$\int \sqrt[3]{r}dr=\frac{3}{4}r^{\frac{4}{3}}$$

$$=\frac{3}{4}r^{\frac{4}{3}}+\frac{3}{2}r^{\frac{2}{3}}+C$$

$$\quad \int _1^8\sqrt[3]{r}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{r}}dr=18-\frac{9}{4}$$

$$\lim _{r\to \:1+}\left(\frac{3}{4}r^{\frac{4}{3}}+\frac{3}{2}r^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)=\frac{9}{4}$$

$$\lim _{r\to \:8-}\left(\frac{3}{4}r^{\frac{4}{3}}+\frac{3}{2}r^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)=18$$

$$=18-\frac{9}{4}$$

$$=\frac{63}{4}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: The final answer is correct, btw why did you use $\lim$?

Comment: Yes! it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is more efficient to get rid of the cube root by enforcing the substitution $r=x^3$ in the very first stage:
$$ \int_{1}^{8}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{r}}+\sqrt[3]{r}\right)\,dr = \int_{1}^{2}3x^2\left(\frac{1}{x}+x\right)\,dx = 3\left[\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4}\right]_{1}^{2}=\frac{63}{4}.\quad\color{green}{\checkmark} $$